# Tengo un problema con JAVA en debian

Tags: java

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Buenas he instalado openJDK 10.0 y apache netbeans 10 y me ha aparecido un fallo rarísimo que no logro solucionares el si

Comment: ¿cual es el problema?

Comment: Que me sale ese mensaje rarisimo y no se que es, lo teno en otros pcs y no me sale ese mensaje.

Comment: Es solo un mensaje que te muestra un flag en la configuracion de java señalando que fuente usa por defecto java. Haciendo una simple búsqueda en google encontre lo siguiente: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38227977/how-to-remove-error-picked-up-java-options-xmx512m, tambien hay videos de ytb: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JF_o8WNt3hs, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R3Hj83J0ekk, etc

Comment: Deduzco entonces que no afecta en nada al lo que programe, muchas gracias.

Comment: Exacto, los errores en softwares profesionales son explicitos, contendran la palabra ERROR o WARNING